# show div if php echo is empty: Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Quick question.

I have the following.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'search/searchpost.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
            $('#default').hide();
        }
     });
  });
 });
 </script>
```

This works fine, but if the echo does NOT contain anything I want it to show the #default div instead of hiding it. Is that possible?

PHP page

```
<?php
require_once('../config/db.php');
require_once('../customLIB/pdo_db.php');
require_once('../models/test.php');
$SalesRep = new SalesRep();

if ($_POST['search']) {
$data = $_POST['search'];
$rep = $SalesRep->getRep($data);

if(!empty($rep)) {

    echo "
     <div class='modal-body clearfix row'>
        <div class='col-md-4 text-center'><img     src='img/salesmap/image.jpg'  alt='Name' /></div>
        <div class='col-md-8 salesman'>
            <h2>Name</h2>
            <p class='salesman-subtxt'>Subtext</p>
            <p class='salesman-phone'><br />
                Office: <br />
                Cell: <br />
                Email: <a href='' target='_blank'></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>";

 }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (data == "") doSmth()`

Comment: Fantastic thanks, make it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't echo anything in case of some parameters are not set, value of `data` is empty string (you can check it with `console.log(data)`), so:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data != "") {
        $('#results').html(data);
        $('#default').hide();
    } else {
        $('#default').show();
    }
}
```